# How can I use REPLACE with LIKE statement SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is what I'm trying:

```
SELECT *

FROM TABLE

WHERE '0.21' LIKE '%' + REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME,'%','[%]') + '%'
```

What I want is to select a record with the value `'21%'` and not `'0%'`.

But all I can get is `'21%' AND '0%'’ or none of both.

Comment: I can't understand this question at all

Comment: please clarify the question.

Comment: Give example data covering all relevant scenarios and desired results. Your description is not clear.

Comment: How about `SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_name = '21%'`

Comment: Mybe you can **[go here and get some help](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150881/a-asking-a-question)**

Comment: @FarewellStackExchange According to my information, you can't cast close votes, you just flag the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This..?

```
Select * from TABLE t
Where t.Column_Name LIKE '0.21%'
--Where you are trying to match a decimal column value
```

Or maybe...

```
Select * from TABLE t
Where REPLACE(t.Column_Name, '%', '') LIKE '0.21%'
--Where you are trying to remove a percentage symbol before matching a decimal column
```

You havent really clarified what you are trying to do, people will struggle to give accurate answers if you dont give a clear explanation.

Comment: It seems like _let me guess_